# R Markdown Knitting header with JPG issue

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I am new to markdown and have to generate a weekly report with the proper header including a jpg image. I have the following yaml

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Author Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
    - \usepackage{float}
    - \usepackage{graphicx}
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \pagestyle{fancy}
    - \pretitle{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{picture.jpg}}
    - \posttitle{\end{center}}
    
mainfont: Calibri
output: 
  pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

Company policy states that all documents have to be in Calibri(I know) which was the main issue prior to this.
When I go to knit I get this error

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 11, column 5 could not find expected ':' at line 12, column 5
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Any help on a resolution is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try again with adding a `-` before `\includegraphics[width=2in]{picture.jpg}}` ?!

Comment: Did as you said and the error now is:

! Undefined control sequence.
l.68 \pretitle
              {\begin{center} 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first error** `Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) :  Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 11, column 5 could not find expected ':' at line 12, column 5` (as described in the question) originates from the fact that you are missing a `-` in line 11, so that line is considered as a key of YAML and since this key is missing a `:`, hence the error.

And after adding `-`, you are having **another error** `! Undefined control sequence. l.68 \pretitle {\begin{center} Error: LaTeX failed to compile` (as said in the comment), because the command `\pretitle` is not recognised here. The command `\pretitle` (and also `\postitle`) comes from the latex package [`titling`](https://texdoc.org/serve/titling.pdf/0) which is not specified here, hence the error.

**Solution**

Simply add the package `titling` using `\usepackage` in `header-includes`.

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Author Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \pretitle{\begin{center}
  - \includegraphics[width=2in]{picture.jpg}}}
  - \posttitle{\end{center}}
mainfont: Calibri
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```